# Fail test when to much assumes fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In JUnit we can use `Assume` in stead of `Assert`.
This has the advantage that the test doesn't fail but it also mark as no full success.

Is there any possibility to configure all `Assume` testing that for xx% have to succeed or else the TestCase will fail?
It's not that we only write `Assume` testing but in some particular cases we need to do so because we don't have an LDAP testing environment and changes there could affect our testing.
If the tests fails => resolve testing before you can release.
With `Assume` we can still release if most of the assumes succeed and refactor the testing when we have time and not in stress of a release.
Of course the success percentage need's to be high like 90 - 95%.
 
I'm now thinking in the direction of creating a static wrapper class where I log the calls and the failures.
Of course I don't want to reinvent the wheel when it already exist with an even better implementation then what I would write.

Comment: Will your customer be satisfied with a system failing in 5% of its tasks?

Comment: @Manu there is a difference between assert and assume. I use assume for checking if a specific user is in a specific group. No test environment means user can leave company and no longer in LDAP. Does this issue has to stop a release or as long I can find minimum 4 out of 5 users it's still good for release.  We can check later what's the issue with that user.

Comment: Personally, I would simply use AssertJ for that. It has soft assertions and it should be easy enough to override that to fail if X have failed and succeed otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can implement a [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) to count the quantity of failed assumes, using [testAssumptionFailure()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html#testAssumptionFailure%28org.junit.runner.notification.Failure%29).

Comment: That's the solution for catching the failed ones. I looked at the documentation but I can't find any count of total assumptions runs.(Description don't tell that also)  I can hardcode the total assumptions but that's a little dirty...

Comment: JUnit can not know upfront, how much assuptions it will have to process. Perhaps you can count the passed assumes as well in the listener, and calculate the quotient afterwards?

Comment: I solved it with the runListener with `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` I check after testing in  `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` the failed assumes with the total run count. If you throw a fail there, it's also persisted to the testresults.  It's not 100% what I wanted because I can't count the total assumes but still better then hardcoding the total assumes methods.